# When does there exist a base of eigenvectors for a matrix?

Tags: matrices

Does there exist a base of eigenvectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0\\-2&0&-1\\-4&2&1\end{pmatrix}?$$
What I know/have done so far:

-The matrix has only one real eigenvalue $\lambda=-1$, with algebraic and geometric multiplicity $1$. According to my understanding, there should exist a base of eigenvectors. Yet there is only one vector that spans the eigenspace of $\lambda=-1$, so I can't find a base of eigenvectors.

My question is why not?

Comment: Why, according to your understanding, should there exist a base of eigenvector?

Comment: @uniquesolution "There exists a basis of eigenvectors if and only if the algebraic and multiplicity of each eigenvalue is the same." This is the case here.

Comment: There is a basis of eigenvectors ... for $\Bbb C^3$.  But NOT $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @Bye_World BUT WHY NOT for $\mathbb{R}^3$? (Sorry for the caps lock, but I've been struggling with this question for a good while now)

Comment: This matrix doesn't have $3$ linearly independent *real* eigenvectors.  It does have $3$ linearly independent *complex* eigenvectors.

Comment: @Bye_World Can you explain why not having $3$ linearly independent real eigenvectors means that there is no basis?

Comment: The definition of *basis* is a set of linearly independent vectors which spans a space.

Comment: @Bye_World Okay, thanks